# Let users access to part of website only if they're approved

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm working with laravel 5.4 and I have part of my website that give download links but I need to give this download links only to users who paid for that links.

Example:
I have courses which users can buy to learn. Each course has different link of downloads. here i want to show download link of exact course that user has bought to him/her and not all the courses for like 30 days.

How can I do that?

> PS: I only need guide about database structures to how to relate
>   specific user to specific course for limited time only.

Thanks.

Comment: What authentication system are you using?

Comment: @Maxime what do you mean? i installed `make:auth` and now i'm using custom routes for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really that experienced with Laravel, but it's very easy to do in PHP. One thing you can do is store information in a session like this:

```
$_SESSION['premium'] = true;
```

So then you can check to see if the session is true like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['premium'] = true) {
    # Paid content
} else {
    echo "Sorry! This is for premium members only!";
}
```

You also have the options of querying the database to see if the user have a column called 'paid' set to 1(true) or 0(false). Which I'm assuming you understand how to do.

**In response to your recent comment:**

Create a table called `purchases` with these columns:

- id
- user_id
- course_id

Then on the page, query that table:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection_variable, "SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE user_id='$_SESSION['username'] AND course_id='$course_id'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    #Show course
} else {
    echo "ERROR MESSAGE HERE";
}
```

Try that and tell me how it goes!

Comment: thanks man, i get your point but i need to know how to connect the user to exact course s(he) paid for, unless all the courses will be open to user once i approve payment!

Comment: @RobertNicjoo Refer to my answer, I had just edited it.

Comment: @hoogleyBoogly I createch purchase table and info i can pass into it now but how about expiring download links?

Comment: @RobertNicjoo You can try to add another column for the purchases table, call it 'expires' and then add a time like 10 days from when the user purchased the course. Use PHP to check the date and compare it to the date in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your users login first.

Create a model for `Purchases` with a `user_id`, `course_id` and timestamps and set up a one to many relationship.

In your logic when someone purchases a course you add a record into your Purchases table above. Supposing you have a listing of these Purchases, you would grab these purchases by

```
User::find(1)->purchases
```

and this would return the purchases they are allowed to download. You would need additional validation using scopes maybe to effect your 30 day availability rule e.g. download is only available if the date today is within 30 days from the `created_at` column.

Comment: thanks man, now i have purchase table and i can get all info of user and his/her orders but still confuse about `scope` and how to make it expire?

Comment: Create a local scope called for example scopeActive and then do a whereRaw on the query object that should only return records where the difference between today and the created_at column should be less than 30days.